# Scrollspy highlighting not working in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having difficulty with ScrollSpy on my web page. I've tried to put the class file indicators into the correct locations but they are still not showing up.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wMwM/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Unix Command Crib Sheet</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="command-crib-sheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".thingy">
    <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
        <h2>Unix Command Crib Sheet</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="centered-nav" class="bs-sidebar hidden-print affix">
          <nav id="thingy" class="nav bs-sidenav">
            <li>
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add a class 'thingy' to
`<div class="container thingy">`

added new css to highlight the text(change style accordingly)

```
li.active a {
        color: red;
    }
```

and finally add this script to page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.thingy'
    });
</script>
```

last but not least i have changed `<nav>` to `<ul>`

```
<nav id="thingy" class="nav bs-sidenav">
```

to

```
<ul id="thingy" class="nav bs-sidenav">
```

That's it..!